# Syntax documentation for a dollar sign in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I came across some HTML recently that denoted a style this way:

```
<style type="text/css">
     ${demo.css}
</style>
```

Obviously, this is including the "demo.css" file. But I've never seen CSS written this way. I've only seen the @import syntax for including files.

A cursory search around Google turned up nothing. Is this syntax documented anywhere? Is this some sort of templating thing?

Comment: _"Obviously, this is including the "demo.css" file."_ Not in plain CSS it's not. There are attribute selectors that use `$`, like `a[href$=".pdf"]`, but that's not what you have.

Comment: This must be templating.

Comment: Some languages like JSP use a syntax like this. ${var_name} will inject that value of a variable var_name on the page.

Comment: @j08691 I think OP meant "obviously the purpose of this code is to include the demo.css file"

Comment: @TylerH - Yes, but in plain CSS it won't do anything. Odds are, as others have mentioned, that there's some sort of templating involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't CSS.

It looks like it is probably part of an HTML template (the syntax is used in Angular, for instance) that will be processed by a programming language before outputting a style element with actual CSS in it.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not using a template, though. This is just a static HTML file I downloaded to demo a Javascript library.

Comment: @dmerica - then it may be the JavaScript that's parsing that code.

Comment: Looking around the directories I downloaded along with this example code, I've noticed that there actually is no demo.css file anywhere. Maybe they left it in on accident, and maybe the $ syntax is leftover from a template they'd used before. But from what you and others have said, this seems to be the correct answer. It's not CSS at all.